# How and why is Apache intercepting some CORS requests to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, apache, cors, passenger

Before Chrome makes a cross-domain AJAX call it makes an OPTIONS check like this:

```
curl \
'https://fubar.com/users/sign_in' \
-X OPTIONS \
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
-H 'Origin: http://snafu.com' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type' \
--compressed \
--insecure \
--verbose
```

(I added `--insecure` and `--verbose` for testing.)

I can see this request in the Apache logs but it doesn't get to Rails.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2018:09:22:44 -0400] "OPTIONS /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

If I remove either the `Access-Control-Request-Method` or `Origin` headers then it *does* pass the request to Rails.

Something about the *combination* of these two headers seems to be causing Apache to handle the request itself and not give Rails a chance to process it.

I am not setting any headers or defining any rewrite rules in the Apache config; it's basically a vanilla install.

I'm not able to find any documentation or configurations explaining why this would be happening and how to prevent it.

Comment: The why is because the specification says and the how is that it terminates the connection after the OPTIONS response.

Answer (score 2):

1) `OPTIONS` HTTP call at `'https://fubar.com/users/sign_in'` performed from chrome browser with request headers `'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST'` and `'Origin: http://snafu.com'`

2) the server at `'https://fubar.com/users/sign_in'` receives the request

**STEP 1**

The routing is handles from either nginx or apache webserver which will first apply their own config rules. This settings are included in the file inside `/etc/apache2` or `/etc/nginx`

For example with nginx you can define rules to `add_header` to the `http` response or settings to redirect to another `url`

for example

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'"
```

this will add the header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'"` to all responses. 
If for example you apply this response to all `OPTIONS` requests, then all subsequent `http` request will be whitelisted from any http `origin`

**STEP 2**

once the nginx/apache redirection rules are applied, the `rails router` receives the request and redirects to your controller.

Here you can still add any header you want inside the controller, you can redirect `OPTIONS` request to a specific controller action, which can add a specific header, be careful to not add twice the same header as that can cause issues.

In this action you can rewrite the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response from the `OPTIONS` request to whitelist only specific origin domains (you just need to write a routing rule which is applied only to `OPTIONS` requests)

The origin domain is written in the header of the request

> request headers `'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST'` and `'Origin: http://snafu.com'`